# lwIP echo server error sending data

Tags: c, tcp, xilinx, lwip, echo-server

I am working with the ethernet communication under echo server lwIP. I would like to capture samples from DMA to the HOST by ethernet. The system captures samples via UART.

I am not able to make lwIP to send more than 2 packages higher than 1500 bytes without waiting for ACK. My application sends packet continuously to the client. Client receives the packet without any delay but it sends the ACK after 200ms (see attached wireshark capture image). LWIP get stuck always waiting for ACK packet before it sends the next packet. My lwIP could only send no more than 2 TCP segment and then wait for ACK. The network delay will cause performance to get down.

Is there any configuration which makes the LWIP to send packet without waiting for the ACK packet? Do you have any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wait how about using UDP instead of TCP? TCP is a stream protocol and is going to ensure that everything arrives and is in-order (so long as there aren't errors). echo usually makes me think of a situation where you don't care about ordering, only whether a particular packet makes it or not and how long it took.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I need to capture millions samples, I probably would lose some samples using UDP, right?. Your suggestion is to use echo server in UDP mode?. regards